# Ubuntu access rights - Mod_Python Permission denied

Tags: python, ubuntu, mod-python, rights-management

I am running Ubuntu with an Apache webserver with Mod_python. The root directory of the web server is `/var/www`
I have a form for uploading files. The uploaded files should be stored in folder `/var/www/xy/uploads` by a python script.
But when I use this script, I receive an error:

```
Permission denied: '/var/www/xy/uploads/316.jpg'
```

Here the relevant parts of the code, that should handle the received files:

```
targetdir_path = "/var/www/xy/uploads"
newid = 316
f = open(os.path.join(targetdir_path,str(newid)+'.jpg'),"w")
```

I assume, there is a problem with the access rights of the uploads directory. They are set to: drwxr-xr-x

Can anyone explain me, what I need to change? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directory permissions are set for only allowing writing for the owner of the directory.
try this:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/xy/
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/wwww/xy/uploads
```

Also, I'd advise against using `mod_python` as it is deprecated, look into `mod_wsgi` instead.